# Siunitx package doesn't compile

Tags: compiling, siunitx

My latex (with Texmaker) doesn't produce pdf when I'm using the siunitx package.
I got my log file ending like this:

```
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command" 
. 
. Defining command \SIlistInBookmark with sig. 'omm' on line 7429.
.................................................
................................................. 
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command" 
. 
. Defining com
```

Does anyone know what the problem is ? I already tried to uninstall the package but nothing changes...

I use these packages too with it :

```
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

Thank you

Edit :

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
This is an example
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: the lines you show are normal, not an error

Comment: Ok this code doesn't work : (I edited my question)

Comment: This code compiles quite normally for me. Do you have the latest version (`2.7k`)?

Comment: I think so I downloaded miktek and texmaker this morning after unistalling it : This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (MiKTeX 2.9.6500 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2018.1.10) and LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because solved by reinstall

Answer (score 1):

I uninstalled both miktek and Latex and installed it again and it worked perfectly.
I hope this might help someone else thank you for trying to help me.